# Are the auto_saved_sqls shown in remote servers?

Tags: mysql

I was trying to find the session id in chrome and I found something that could give advantage to an attacker if they can see it.

In chrome I opened the console > Application > Local storage and I found auto_saved_sql as key and has a query:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable Where... // this provides the person who sees it the names of a table and some parameters and I think this could be used against the webpage.
```

I have only tested my site locally. If they are shown is there a way to disable it or encrypt it or something like that?

Comment: Yea, any update on this? I too suddenly noticed it on my Angular 4 app. https://i.imgur.com/04khRr8.png

Comment: Yep, I tested my site online and it doesn't show any of that to the user. I think it's just a feature to speed up a little bit the work for coders.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

5 months after the question Im still working on my site but now it's working online, I checked and no queries are shown in a non-local website, I made some requests that execute queries and they are not stored, it's the same code as when I asked this question running in a server, I hope this solves anyone else's doubts. [image: I]
I blurred the site domain because I don't want spam. :)

Answer (score 5):

You can see this auto_saved_sql when you open your phpMyAdmin and website in the same browser. That is a value from your phpMyAdmin, but not your website. So, don't worry. Because both serve same servers, you can easily get confused for this issue.