# What sets the 'auto_saved_sql' key and why? found in chrome devtools under local storage

Tags: php, mysql, google-chrome, devtools

I was inspecting my web app in chrome and I found a key called 'auto_saved_sql' holding this query statement:

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE........
```

I found it under console > Application > Local storage.

[image]

My app is still under development and its running on my local machine.

I want to know **what sets this key** and/or **why does it exist**?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Are the auto_saved_sqls shown in remote servers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45618584/are-the-auto-saved-sqls-shown-in-remote-servers)

Comment: No, please read my question again, I'm looking for what sets it. I also know how to use google search.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see you mention in your post that you already know about this link. I thought it could help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because of your Localhost/phpmyadmin local storage cache, that's why you can see autoSaved.sql value under console > Application > Local storage.

You can test from your side, clear your browser cache and close all tab include phpmyadmin and again open your application console > Application > Local storage and look no more any autosaved_sql key value.

Reference.
[For PHPmyadmin reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6Y6wV.png)
After execute SQL query in the PHPmyadmin then see console > Application > Local storage. you can see what query you execute will be added in the local storage.
[Localhost console > Application > Local storage reference image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UgDh.png)

Comment: Thanks!! I was worried it's a virus.